# Identify first occurrence of group of repeated values in excel, but groups could be repeated

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

So I have a column in excel that looks like the first column in this screenshot:
[Data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXZU5.png)

The "existing result" column comes from this formula which is easily found from googling:
(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1)+0

However, my list has groups of repeated values that repeat. As you can see from the screenshot, the second group of B's are ignored because they have already shown up previously.

The "required result" column was entered in manually with the only difference being the 1 at the first instance of the second set of B's.

If anyone can help me with a formula to account for the repeated groups, it would be much appreciated. I've been banging my head against the wall for over an hour here.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B2` enter

```
=IF(A1<>A2, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Wow. I could have sworn I tried this approach and it didn't work. I have no idea what I did wrong when I originally did it but clearly I did something wrong. Thanks for your help.